# How to ensure that the table will be square on any screen size. No matter how many rows/columns

Tags: css

I am trying to style a table of two rows and sixteen columns to be always square on any screen resolution. So cells are narrow rectangles in portrait layout. I tried the following:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="content"></div></td>
        ... *another 14 td's*   
        <td><div class="content"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="content"></div></td>
        ... *another 14 td's*       
        <td><div class="content"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
   width:100%;
}
table:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   margin-top: 100%;
}
td {
   width: 6.25%;
   position: relative;
}
td .content {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   background: yellow;
   border: 1px solid brown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there's no real good way to set the height relative to the elements width yet. One solution you could try is making the width and height static numbers and then use media queries so it doesn't run off the page. something like this:

```
.table {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .table {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .table {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

To answer that second question:
Bootstrap uses flexbox which unless you specify otherwise will try to fit everything on the same line. If you set `flex-wrap: wrap;` to that bootstrap class then it should allow things that are 100% to fill that row and bump other stuff up or down.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself but still did not understand it. So my question changes from “How” to “Why”. I also forgot to mention, that I use Bootstrap 4 on this page. So the whole solution is below – it works, I tested. But if I add another `<div>` before `<div class = “square”>`, it won’t work. It only works if `<div class = “col-*-*>` (Bootstrap's class) is before `<div class = “square”>`.

HTML:

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-sm-8">
        <div class = "square">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="content"></div></td>
                    ... *another 14 td's*

                    <td><div class="content"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="content"></div></td>
                    ... *another 14 td's*

                    <td><div class="content"></div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.square {
   width:100%;
   height: 100%
}
.square:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   margin-top: 100%;
}
table {
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}
td {
   width: 6.25%;
   position: relative;
}
td .content {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   background: yellow;
   border: 1px solid brown;
}
```